# can we set array to dyanamic drop down list in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, drop-down-menu

This is the picture where new row will add after user click's on [add more] button..It works fine but i want to send these values using ajax.I can access all textbox values with array map function in ajax except dropdown values.
[image]

how I would implement it with this example. Thanks!

```
    <tr>
       <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
       <td>1.</td>
       <td> <select  name='relation[]' id='relation' >
              <option value='brother'>Brother</option>
              <option value='sister'>Sister</option>
           </select>
       </td>
       <td><input type='text' id='name' name='name[]'></td>
       <td><input type='text' id='school' name='school[]'></td> 
       <td<select name='medium[]' id='medium'>
             <option value='marathi'>marathi</option>
             <option value='english'>english </option>
           </select>
       </td>

                          <td> <?php                                                                                    
                            //Get all class data
                            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `class_master`");

                            //Count total number of rows
                            $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
                        ?>                        
                        <select name="std[]" id="std" class="form-control focusedInput" >
                            <option value="">Select Standard </option>
                            <?php
                                if($rowCount > 0){                                                        
                                  while($row72 = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                                      echo '<option value="'.$row72['class_id'].'">'.$row72['class_name'].'</option>';
                                  }
                                } else {
                                    echo '<option value="">Class not available</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
```

Comment: Your code is working for dynamic values or not if yes then when you want to call ajax, I mean at which event?

Comment: on button click event i have sent all values

Answer (score 0):

User form at the starting of the page and and while sending data using ajax just use ("#form_id").serialize() instead of using array map , serialize is the method of jquery. Please read about the method and your problem will be solved.

Comment: i am using this code with form step wizard with 5 steps and also sending images so thats y i am facing problem